# how to deploy django app on cpanel and automate it with python selelnium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, cpanel

I have developed and deployed the Django app for selenium automation on the Godaddy Cpanel server, which automatically opens the selenium chrome browser and extracts the data from a website. It works perfectly in the localhost server but when I deployed it into the Cpanel server it's not working/chromedriver not initializing. How should I configure Cpanel to run python selenium driver on page load or button click.

```
def getrate(request):
   if request.user.is_authenticated:
       if request.method == "GET" :
            from selenium import webdriver
            from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
            driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
            driver.get("https://www.nytimes.com/international/"))
```

Comment: Make sure you have the proper account/server on Godaddy... the standard shared hosting will not support running python or executables like webdriver.  Also be sure to check permissions... the driver manager is going to want to write the webdriver file and some kind of config.  (You should probably just place the webdriver file(s) manually...)

Comment: also remember that you'll need to install a browser... (or use something like HTMLUnit as your webdriver)

Comment: @pcalkins thanks for the info.. kindly provide me with more information like which account/server support Django selenium web driver automation..and configuration

Comment: basically you want a dedicated server so you can install what you need on it.  Your HTML GUI would take whatever input you need and output your json.